# How do I share a private variable among tasks in Flink (Scala)?

Tags: multithreading, scala, parallel-processing, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to share a private variable in my Flink job (Scala) across the parallel tasks of Flink. My code is something like this :

```
object myJob extends flinkJob {
 private val myVariable = someValue

 def run(params) : Unit = {
  //Stream processing
  //myVariable is used here in the ProcessFunction
 }
}
```

When I run this job with some parallelization, will there be a single copy of "myVariable" shared across all of the Flink tasks? If not, how can I ensure that only one single copy of the variable is used and maintained across all of the parallel tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Since parallelized copies of your operator run as tasks in separate JVMs, there can be no "sharing" of a variable. What you can do is use a [BroadcastStream](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/BroadcastStream.html) to share the same data with multiple tasks. If you need to be able to update the variable, then you'll need to look at using [iterations](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/batch/iterations.html), or store the variable in an external system that you can regularly query.

Comment: BroadcastStream will broadcast a stream of data but what I have is a single variable that it being updated by every parallel task. How can I even share a data structure like a dictionary, using BroadcastStream ?

Comment: Think of your dictionary entries as key/value pairs. Each update to a KV is a record that iterates back to the broadcast stream, and thus gets sent to every parallelized operator.